# How to fill OpenVPN connection data in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, vpn, openvpn

In [kubuntu](/questions/tagged/kubuntu) 18.04 and from the Network Manager, I have tried to create new connection and I have chosen the type to be **OpenVPN**

[image]

**After that, I have gotten the following window screenshot**

[image]

**How could I fill the correct** connection data in the above window?
In other words, What is the gateway URL/IP that I have to know, How could I get the certificates?